# Why does calling my wife's phone go straight to VoiceMail?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-droid-incredible, verizon, htc-thunderbolt, voicemail

When using my Verizon HTC Thunderbolt running CyanogenMod to call my wife's Verizon HTC Incredible, also running CyanogenMod, it always goes straight to Voice Mail.  I can call other Verizon phones with no issue and my wife can call me with no issue and my wife can receive calls from other Verizon lines with no issue and she can call me with no issue.  Issue is only from my phone to hers.  I called Verizon and they said it is not a network issue and suggested an installed application might be causing the issue.  They suggested to put both phones into Safe Mode boot.  I was able to do this for Incredible, but failed using the directions they provided for the Thunderbolt. They said after boot starts, hold down volume down key for boot process on Thunderbolt.

How can I debug this issue of my phone going straight to Voice Mail?  What would cause just my phone to experience this issue?  Any advise and suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be your number being "blacklisted" on your wife's phone. There are a lot of apps on the playstore offering this feature, and some Android versions can do so on their own (just configure the contact in your contacts list correspondingly).

So here's what you could do:

1. check with your SIM card placed in some other phone (if that option exists; at least here in Europe we can move the SIM card around). Your call should be still blocked/routed to voicemail then, so you know the issue is not with your phone (e.g. dialing some prefix/postfix)
2. check your wife's phone for installed apps like Advanced Call Blocker etc.
3. check your wife's phonebook (errm, or let her check ;) for your record there and see whether it is blacklisted. If unsure, just delete it temporarily, then call her again.
4. At least CyanogenMod lets you manage a separate blacklist. With CM, it is found in the call settings. Check whether your number made it into this place.
5. if the problem still exists, repeat step 1. with your wife's phone (again, if possible)

My guess is either 2., 3., or 4. will reveal the cause.

Comment: cyanogenmod definitely has this feature

Comment: @ce4 oh yeah -- a separate blacklist in the call settings. Yikes... Will add this to my answer. Tnx for the hint!